# Unable to Open an Python Selenium exe file in Windows 10

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I Have converted a Python Selenium file into .exe using pyinstaller. However when I open the file the CMD screen flashes and Thats It, The GUI screen to run the executable file is not observed. My Code uses inputs from An Excel

Pre - Condition which I followed

- Web Driver path is updated to the path where the Exe file is located
- Changed the Excel path to the folder where EXE file is located

Could you help me with this option?

Intent: Trying to Distribute my automation script to my Peers for Testing purpose

Comment: can you post the command you ran to get the .exe

Comment: Sure Shadow the command which i used was pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py

Comment: try pyinstaller --onefile -w 'pythonScriptName.py' and do you get a error?

Comment: Hi Shadow, I tried with the above and now when I open the file i get "Failed to execute script pythonScriptName "

Comment: can you add a screen shot?

Comment: I am not able to attach the screen shot, The exact error is like this A modal with Fatal Error as heading and "Failed to execute script pythonScriptName " message

Comment: If you open the cmd line window and then execute the script the window won't disappear and you'll be able to capture the original error message.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cant specify the webdriver path like this, since the path differs from computer to computer. try to input it in the same folder all together and then let the path field for the path of the webdriver free. might or might not work